# How to get the entire list of recursively removed objects from destroy_all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I.e., with `dependent: :destroy`, associated records are deleted. However, `#destroy_all` only returns the list of "top level" deleted objects.

I'd like to show a *complete* list of objects deleted. E.g., when a user deletes their account, giving transparency of the data deleted.

One idea is to first determine which objects *would* be deleted via a call to `#destroy_all`, but I don't know how that could be done.